# Cannot add the same member twice to a SerializationInfo object

Tags: c#, coded-ui-tests

I have been running into an error thrown by the "Coded UI Test Builder" whenever I hit the "Add and Generate" button to generate the code in visual C# 2012 ultimate.

Coded UI test builder is not pointing exactly where the error is occurring.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hope you've found a resolution to this.  If not, are there any other parts to the error message?  The name of an object that it can't add or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is occurring most likely because the same element at the same node is being added to the UI map. I would go through it with a fine tooth comb and check for any duplicates that might be occurring.